# iPhone4s turned itself down then turned on by itself then turns off by itself again and again

Tags: iphone

While I was charging my iPhone4s it turned itself down then it turned on again by itself then it turns on again then off then on and so on. How will I fix my phone?

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas:

1. Try stopping all apps and then restarting your phone
2. Is this happening after you installed/updated a certain app? Try removing it
3. Backup your phone, reset it to factory settings, then restore it from the backup
4. Take it to an Apple Service Center

Comment: Ithappened while i was using it while charging.